# How to add a media with PHP

Tags: images, uploads, media

I have more than 1000 pictures on my webserver, uploaded with FTP in a local folder ( `/home/chris/pictures` )

Is there a way to add them as a well known media to wordpress in PHP and get their id?

```
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    $filemakerID = get_post_meta($post_id, 'filemaker_id', true);

    $file['url']='/home/chris/picture_export/'.$filemakerID.'.jpeg';
    $file['type'] = 'image/jpeg';

    //THE DREAMED FUNCTION WOULD BE USED THIS WAY
    $photo_id = awesome_function( $file, $post_id);

    add_post_meta($post_id, 'photo', $photo_id );
}
```

As you noticed, my photo is used in a custom field `photo` as well.

After hours on google dans codex, I noticed how poorly documented these functions are. Maybe I just could not figure out the correct keywords to search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, each post has a filemaker, and each filemaker has only one photo? The structure is kind of unclear.

Anyways, one way is top use `media_sideload_image` like below.

However, `media_sideload_image` **WON'T** work with local files (a path on your filesystem), so you need to change your $file['url'] to be a valid URL (http://yourhomepage.com/chris/pictures, for example). If you can't do that, you need to use [wp_upload_bits](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_bits) and [wp_insert_attachment](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment), but that way is a lot more work/harder.

```
function awesome_function($file, $post_id) {

    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin' . '/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin' . '/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin' . '/includes/media.php');

    // upload image to server
    media_sideload_image($file['url'], $post_id);

    // get the newly uploaded image
    $attachments = get_posts( array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'number_posts' => 1,
        'post_status' => null,
        'post_parent' => $post_id,
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'order' => 'DESC',) 
    );

    // returns the id of the image
    return $attachments[0]->ID;
}
```

Comment: Actually your answer is so simple that it IS awesome :). Sadly I got errors `Fatal error: Call to undefined function media_sideload_image()` so I added `require_once( '....../wp-admin/includes/media.php');` and now got a follow error: `'Fatal error: Call to undefined function download_url() in ......./wp-admin/includes/media.php on line 598'`    I keep trying

Comment: Try including /wp-admin/includes/media.php, /wp-admin/includes/file.php and /wp-admin/includes/image.php and see if that works.

Comment: worked with these 3 require_once . Thank you so much.